# How to use class based views in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

I am trying to use class based views in my FastApi project to reduce redundancy of code. Basically I need CRUD functionality for all of my models and therefor would have to write the same routes over and over again. I created a small example project to display my progress so far, but I ran into some issues.

I know there is this [Fastapi-utils](https://fastapi-utils.davidmontague.xyz/user-guide/class-based-views/) but as far as I understand only reduces the number of Dependencies to call and is no longer maintained properly (last commit was March 2020).

I have some arbitrary pydantic Schema/Model. The SQLAlchemy models and DB connection are irrelevant for now.

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel

class ObjBase(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str]

class ObjCreate(ObjBase):
    pass

class ObjUpdate(ObjBase):
    pass

class Obj(ObjBase):
    id: int
```

A BaseService class is used to implement DB access. To simplify this there is no DB access right now and only get (by id) and list (all) is implemented.

```
from typing import Any, Generic, List, Optional, Type, TypeVar
from pydantic import BaseModel


SchemaType = TypeVar("SchemaType", bound=BaseModel)
CreateSchemaType = TypeVar("CreateSchemaType", bound=BaseModel)
UpdateSchemaType = TypeVar("UpdateSchemaType", bound=BaseModel)

class BaseService(Generic[SchemaType, CreateSchemaType, UpdateSchemaType]):
    def __init__(self, model: Type[SchemaType]):
        self.model = model

    def get(self, id: Any) -> Any:
        return {"id": id}

    def list(self, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100) -> Any:
        return [
            {"id": 1},
            {"id": 2},
        ]
```

This BaseService can then be inherited by a ObjService class providing these base functions for the previously defined pydantic Obj Model.

```
from schemas.obj import Obj, ObjCreate, ObjUpdate
from .base import BaseService

class ObjService(BaseService[Obj, ObjCreate, ObjUpdate]):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ObjService, self).__init__(Obj)
```

In the **init**.py file in this directory a function is provided to get an ObjService instance.

```
from fastapi import Depends
from .obj import ObjService

def get_obj_service() -> ObjService:
    return ObjService()
```

So far everything is working. I can inject the Service Class into the relevant FastApi routes. But all routes need to be written for each model and CRUD function. Making it tedious when providing the same API endpoints for multiple models/schemas. Therefor my thought was to use something similar to the logic behind the BaseService by providing a BaseRouter which defines these routes and inherit from that class for each model.

The BaseRouter class:

```
from typing import Generic, Type, TypeVar
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends
from pydantic import BaseModel
from services.base import BaseService

SchemaType = TypeVar("SchemaType", bound=BaseModel)
CreateSchemaType = TypeVar("CreateSchemaType", bound=BaseModel)
UpdateSchemaType = TypeVar("UpdateSchemaType", bound=BaseModel)

class BaseRouter(Generic[SchemaType, CreateSchemaType, UpdateSchemaType]):
    def __init__(self, schema: Type[SchemaType], prefix: str, service: BaseService):
        self.schema = schema
        self.service = service
        
        self.router = APIRouter(
            prefix=prefix
        )

        self.router.add_api_route("/", self.list, methods=['GET'])
        self.router.add_api_route("/{id}", self.get, methods=['GET'])


    def get(self, id):
        return self.service.get(id)

    def list(self):
        return self.service.list()
```

The ObjRouter class:

```
from schemas.obj import Obj, ObjCreate, ObjUpdate
from .base import BaseRouter
from services.base import BaseService

class ObjRouter(BaseRouter[Obj, ObjCreate, ObjUpdate]):
    def __init__(self, prefix: str, service: BaseService):
        super(ObjRouter, self).__init__(Obj, prefix, service)
```

The **init**.py file in that directory

```
from fastapi import Depends
from services import get_obj_service
from services.obj import ObjService
from .obj import ObjRouter

def get_obj_router(service: ObjService = Depends(get_obj_service())) -> ObjRouter:
    return ObjRouter("/obj", service).router
```

In my main.py file this router is added to the FastApi App.

```
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from routes import get_obj_router

app = FastAPI()

app.include_router(get_obj_router())
```

When starting the app the routes Get "/obj" and Get "/obj/id" show up in my Swagger Docs for the project. But when testing one of the endpoints I am getting an AttributeError: 'Depends' object has no attribute 'list'

As far as I understand Depends can only be used in FastApi functions or functions that are dependecies themselves. Therefor I tried altering the app.include_router line in my main.py by this

```
app.include_router(Depends(get_obj_router()))
```

But it again throws an AttributeError: 'Depends' object has no attribute 'routes'.

Long story short question: What am I doing wrong? Is this even possible in FastApi or do I need to stick to defining the same CRUD Api Endpoints over and over again?

The reason I want to use the Dependenvy Injection capabilities of FastApi is that later I will use the following function call in my Service classes to inject the DB session and automatically close it after the request:

```
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()
```

As far as I understand this is only possible when the highest call in the dependency hierachy (Route depends on Service depends on get_db) is done by a FastApi Route.

PS: This is my first question on StackOverflow, please be gentle.

Comment: Hey I am just trying to recreate your problem, but I believe you miscopied the ObjectRouter. It seems to be the ObjectService instead. Could you update your question?

Comment: I updated the code, it should now be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

since your question is understandably very long, I will post a full working example at the bottom of this answer.

Dependencies in FastAPI are callables that can modify an endpoints parameters and pass values down to them. In the api model they work in the endpoint level. To pass-on any dependency results you need to explicitly pass them to the controller function.

In the example below I have created a dummy `Session` class and a dummy session injection function (`injecting_session`). Then I have added this dependency to the `BaseRouter` functions get and list and passed the result on to the `BaseObject` class `get` and `list` functions.

As promised; A fully working example:

```py
from typing import Optional, TypeVar, Type, Generic, Any, Union, Sequence
from fastapi import Depends, APIRouter, FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel


class ObjBase(BaseModel):
    name: Optional[str]


class ObjCreate(ObjBase):
    pass


class ObjUpdate(ObjBase):
    pass


class Obj(ObjBase):
    id: int


SchemaType = TypeVar("SchemaType", bound=BaseModel)
CreateSchemaType = TypeVar("CreateSchemaType", bound=BaseModel)
UpdateSchemaType = TypeVar("UpdateSchemaType", bound=BaseModel)


class Session:
    def __str__(self):
        return "I am a session!"


async def injecting_session():
    print("Creating Session")
    return Session()


class BaseService(Generic[SchemaType, CreateSchemaType, UpdateSchemaType]):
    def __init__(self, model: Type[SchemaType]):
        self.model = model

    def get(self, id: Any, session: Session) -> Any:
        print(session)
        return {"id": id}

    def list(self, session: Session) -> Any:
        print(session)
        return [
            {"id": 1},
            {"id": 2},
        ]


class ObjService(BaseService[Obj, ObjCreate, ObjUpdate]):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ObjService, self).__init__(Obj)


def get_obj_service() -> ObjService:
    return ObjService()


SchemaType2 = TypeVar("SchemaType2", bound=BaseModel)
CreateSchemaType2 = TypeVar("CreateSchemaType2", bound=BaseModel)
UpdateSchemaType2 = TypeVar("UpdateSchemaType2", bound=BaseModel)


class BaseRouter(Generic[SchemaType2, CreateSchemaType2, UpdateSchemaType2]):
    def __init__(self, schema: Type[SchemaType2], prefix: str, service: BaseService):
        self.schema = schema
        self.service = service

        self.router = APIRouter(
            prefix=prefix
        )

        self.router.add_api_route("/", self.list, methods=['GET'])
        self.router.add_api_route("/{id}", self.get, methods=['GET'])

    def get(self, id, session=Depends(injecting_session)):
        return self.service.get(id, session)

    def list(self, session=Depends(injecting_session)):
        return self.service.list(session)


class ObjRouter(BaseRouter[Obj, ObjCreate, ObjUpdate]):
    def __init__(self, path, service):
        super(ObjRouter, self).__init__(Obj, path, service)


def get_obj_router(service=get_obj_service()) -> APIRouter:  # returns API router now
    return ObjRouter("/obj", service).router


app = FastAPI()
app.include_router(get_obj_router())
```

By adding parameters to `injecting_session()` you can add parameters to all endpoints that use the dependency.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my question above. I would like to use the Dependency Injection functionality of FastApi because this then makes it easier using the DB session etc. Therfore dropping the Depends is not an option.

Comment: Hey, I just updated my answer based on your comment. You want to add a dependency when you add the api route. Check `BaseRouter` in my updated code. In this example I am just injecting some parameters like the example on the fastapi website, but you can do whatever you want from here.

Comment: How can these parameters be accessed in the get() function for example?

Comment: I honestly still don't exactly understand what you are trying to do, but I just updated my answer again. This time showing how you could use a dependency injection to get a session to the controller function. If you are only looking to get a session to the controllers it might be more useful to use a decorator that passes a session to your function instead.

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue I think. I did not think about adding the dependency to the function that gets added to the router. I am also not sure if what I am doing is correct or follows any good coding strandard, but for now this makes it more maintainable I think. Thank you very much!

Comment: No worries! Trying to automate routes and controllers seems like a smart move. I have in the past broken standards to write better and more maintainable code. It just needs to be documented well. Good luck with your project!

Comment: CheelHorn Thanks for sharing your brilliant approach and explaining it to this level of details!!!

@Juhuja Thanks for the inspiring Answer!! unfortunately i dont get to understand why you decided to use two different typevars : CreateSchemaType / CreateSchemaType2 one for the service and one for the routing part.

is it just for the sake of separation of concerns or is there any other thoughts behind it?? this is puzzeling me a couple of days now :) would be more than happy to get your point of view!

thanks

Comment: @CheelHorn I think what happened is that I tried to mimic the original code closely for OP to understand my answer. In the code he posted he repeated the typevars probably for better understanding and I just copied them and renamed them as they had the same name. Given that they represent the same thing there should probably be no issue in reusing the first definition.

Comment: @atlasloewenherz looking back at this after half a year I am not sure anymore. Normally I would use different Schemas for the Service and the Router classes for the separation of concerns e.g. to hide some internal columns from the API. But I think in this example it was just a copy and paste issue as Juhuja guessed.

Comment: @atlasloewenherz I mainly followed this tutorial: https://www.patrick-muehlbauer.com/articles/fastapi-with-sqlalchemy. Maybe you can take a look